# update data where IN list asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
Dim nilx As String = textbox1.text --> (example. data like this. "10001,010001")

Using koneksi As New SqlConnection(stringkoneksi)

koneksi.Open()

Dim perintah As SqlCommand = koneksi.CreateCommand

perintah.CommandText = "update mytabledata set rumus='" & TextBox2.Text & "' 
where code in (" & nilx & ") "

perintah.CommandType = CommandType.Text 

perintah.ExecuteNonQuery()

koneksi.Close()
```

error when execute
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '123test' to data type int

because in mytabledata there is code 123test, if i delete code 123test running well

so how to update data where code in (" & nilx & ")

error when execute
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '123test' to data type int

because in mytabledata have code 123test, if i delete code 123test running well

so how to update data where code in (" & nilx & ")
if i have data  nilx = "10001,010001,9912AA,1123BC"

Comment: you CODE Datatype is INT then use code in (10001,10002)  But CODE datatype is varchar then use also ('10001','10002')

Comment: thanks so much it's running well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes in `nilx` must be in single quotes:

```
"'10001','010001','9912AA','1123BC'"
```

Also, use parameterized queries [SQL Injection And Parameterized Queries](https://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx?SQL+Injection+And+Parameterized+Queries). Don't just concatenate `TextBox2.Text` in your commands.